# Problems using NTFS file system with kali linux

Tags: windows, dual-boot, kali-linux, ntfs

Using kali linux 1.0 in dual boot with windows 8.
I have an NTFS partition (D: on windows)
I usually mount it on both OS.
I face the following problem

Windows disk repair utility keeps on reporting errors frequently. After a repair it appears again after a few days.

Is this avoidable problems or do i have to switch to some other file system?

Comment: Which error do you get from Linux when you try to access directories? By the way, if "Windows disk repair utility keeps on reporting errors frequently" it seems that you have problems on ntfs partition.

Comment: no error, i just cannot see some directories in nautilus or ls command , but they do exist when i see them through windows explorer

Comment: Did you find your folders inside ntfs partition by running this `root@code:/media# cd 01CD1F0FE77B9960` and then `ls`.

Comment: no, ls command also fails to show some directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ujjaval mentioned, Windows 8 does some funny stuff with files as part of its windows fast start feature. This will result in filesystem problems when accessing by linux.

According to the  [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G) there are two known solutions:

- Do not *shutdown or hibernate*  prior to booting linux, instead reboot. If you shutdown or hibernate it will utilize fast start feature and cause problems.
- You can disable the fast start feature:

  ```
  powercfg /h off
  ```

You can also disable fast startup feature with the [GUI according to this article](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3152).

Comment: disabling the fast startup feature is the solution to all problems in the quetion.

Answer (score 0):

What i found is that windows 8 stores files for faster startup in the same format as hibernation files, which cannot be accessed.. so try rebooting into linux and not after shutdon of windows..

Save your data.. and USE windows disk (both 7 and 8) to convert fs to GPT.. then first install windows8 in UEFI and then Kali linux UEFI comapatible.. this will solve the error problem

But i dont know about kali linux UEFI compatibility.. its only after ubuntu 13.10 and kali is direct devian based.. so other option is

use Windows 8 in GPT in UEFI.. and Linux in Legacy mode.. so you will only have a single os in startup.. and to shift to other os.. change the boot mode

Answer (score 0):

- Check Hard Disk for Errors
- Change Paging File Size
- Change File Security Settings
- Change Group Policy Editor Settings

Details are:

http://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Windows_8_NTFS_FILE_ERROR